# What is the correct way to use wide-char ncurses on Debian/Ubuntu?

Tags: c, ubuntu, ncurses

I'm writing an application that uses ncurses.

In Debian and Ubuntu, I have the choice between these packages:

- libncurses5-dev
- libncursesw5-dev

The `w` version includes wide-char support, which is what I want.

However, if I only install `libndursesw5-dev`, I get an error message when I compile with `-lncurses` or `-lncursesw` where it tells me it can't find `curses.h` or `ncurses.h`.

Installing both `libncurses5-dev` and `libncursesw5-dev` and using `-lncursesw` works, but I'm not sure if that is the proper way or just coincidentially seems to work. Using `-lncurses` will bring in a non-wide-char library.

For reference, on Mac OS X 10.11, `-lncurses` works (with wide-char support) and `-lncursesw` doesn't work at all.

Comment: This question should be moved to AskUbuntu, since it's dealing with how Ubuntu specifically packages their libs. My guess would be `libncursesw5-dev` depends on the normal `libncurses5-dev` package to work, merely adding wide-char support.

Comment: On debian `#include <ncursesw/ncurses.h>` and compile with `-lncursesw`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debian installs the two headers

```
/usr/include/curses.h
/usr/include/ncursesw/curses.h
```

as a workaround for compatibility.  The latter is "mostly" compatible, but only at compile-time.  For instance the `WINDOW` structure is larger in the latter.  The first (`/usr/include/curses.h`) is "standard", but preceded the ncursesw library by several years.  Because some of the platforms to which ncurses was ported do not use ncurses as the system curses library (e.g., Solaris), provision was made for putting ncurses' header in a subdirectory to avoid overwriting (or conflicting with) the system's standard `curses.h` (see the ncurses FAQ *[Is the ncurses library compatible with my system?](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#compatible_lib)*).

Since Debian started with ncurses as the system curses library, its packagers chose to use the same workaround to avoid conflict between ncurses and ncursesw.  Packagers on some other systems could choose to put *both* in subdirectories and make a link in their packaging scripts like

```
/usr/include/curses -> /usr/include/curses/ncurses.h
```

I recall that Cygwin did something like that, and omitted the link for `unctrl.h` (a bug, because it too is a standard header).

For OSX, the system provides only ncurses (not ncursesw), and most people using ncursesw do this via something like MacPorts, which installs the *ncursesw* header (which works well enough if the application defines `_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED` when compiling for ncursesw,
since the declaration of `WINDOW` is ifdef'd to allow either library to be supported).  The Debian packagers were more cautious and chose to keep the headers separate.